# Why doesn't GNOME Terminal 3.38.0 show the resize information popup?

Tags: gnome-terminal

On a brand new computer I noticed that GNOME Terminal 3.38.0 does not show the little popup in the center showing me the row and column size as I drag the window border.

On my old computer I'm running GNOME Terminal 3.36.2, and the popup works fine.

Another problem with GNOME Terminal 3.38.0:  when I click the "Terminal" menu and click one of the numbered size options, e.g. "1. 80x24, 2: 80x43", it does absolutely nothing.  It does not change the size of the window.  This works fine in GNOME 3.36.2.

So my question is:  Why did GNOME Terminal suffer this regression going from 3.36.2 to 3.38.0?

Comment: Oh this is interesting.  If I switch from one color scheme to another, and then back again, the size pop-up is restored.

However, the "Terminal" menu sizing choices still do not work in GNOME Terminal 3.38.0.

Comment: "menu sizing choices still do not work" — I guess if they are present in the menu but don't take effect whatsoever, it could be a bug; look around on launchpad.net, maybe you spot a report already submitted...

Comment: I searched there earlier, and I was going to report a bug there but the instructions for bug reporting were quite daunting.  I'll take a look again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled Wayland and it worked!

In `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, uncomment the line:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```